# Visual Studio Debugging with Silverlight 4 and Firefox

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, firefox, silverlight-4.0, breakpoints

When trying to debug a Silverlight 4 application in Visual Studio 2010 with Firefox as my browser, I am unable to hit any breakpoints. I get the message "breakpoint will not currently be hit".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is the solution that worked for me when debugging was not working in Firefox:

1. Type "about:config" into the address bar of Firefox
2. Find the property named "dom.ipc.plugins.enabled"
3. Change the value from true to false by double clicking
4. Restart all Firefox browsers
5. Go back to Visual Studio and start debugging!

Hope this saves someone else some time!

Comment: I don't recommend using this setting; because this causes Silverlight to run under the Firefox process. So if Silverlight crashes, your browser goes down with it. Also, it can cause some strange issues with Silverlight Pop-up boxes; like the one requesting Microphone access (See [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=602502) bug in Bugzilla). Use Nathan's solution below.

Comment: @CoreyLarson though I've not run into any problems as of yet, thanks for the comments! I might have just been lucky because I don't use silverlight often at all. +1 for the comment though cheers

Comment: Setting the "dom.ipc.plugins.enabled" introduces strange behavior. I am using Silverlight 4. All my popup windows are not clickable in firefox when i set this option to false.

Answer (score 10):

Firefox hosts silverlight (and other plugins) in a sandboxed process called `plugin-helper.exe`.

Manually attach your debugger to the correct instance of this (it'll have "Silverlight" in the process type field), and you get your debugging back, and you get to keep your plugin sandboxing too.

EDIT:
Looks like someone else sick of doing this by hand and wrote an [VS2010 addon](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Firefox-Debug-Helper-%28Visual-Studio-Add-in%29.aspx) to automatically attach to `plugin-helper.exe`.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate method Nathan! Cheers

Comment: Now it is `plugin-container`: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/What%20is%20plugin-container