# How do I debug Silverlight not working in Firefox/chrome/Safari?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, safari, silverlight-5.0

I have a problem where a Silverlight system I have developed is working perfectly in Internet Explorer but not at all in Chrome or Firefox

I have no idea where to start to try to figure out what the problem is?

Chrome just says Cannot load Silverlight plugin which is obviously useless from a debugging point of view

Firefox just displays the container page

I have used firebug and interestingly Firefox makes no attempt to download the xap files?

This is a major issue and any pointers would be very helpful!

The application does make use of Prism which may be something to do with it

Paul

Comment: After launching the app from VS, have you tried attaching the debugger when you are using Chrome or Firefox?  Debug->Attach to Process, look for Silverlight in a Chrome/Firefox process?

Comment: Similar question about debugging Silverlight in Firefox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965039/visual-studio-debugging-with-silverlight-4-and-firefox